# JavaScript filter by all values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Here my code and what i tried :

```
filterPrestationsByServiceSelected(arrayOfServices) {
    console.log(arrayOfServices); // ['Repassage', 'Couture']
    this.filteredPrestationsByService = this.filteredPrestations.filter(item => item.service.name.includes(arrayOfServices.values()));
},
```

I want to filter all items of `this.filteredPrestations` where the `service name` contains values of the `arrayOfServices`.

Anyone have an idea of what i can do ?
Thank's !

Comment: Can you add a example array?

Comment: ['Repassage', 'Couture', 'Automobile']

Comment: remove the .values at the end. `arrayOfServices.values()`

Comment: `this.filteredPrestationsByService = this.filteredPrestations.filter(item => arrayOfServices.includes(item));` ?

Comment: Wow ! That's works ! @EugenSunic Thank's !

Answer (score 1):

Remove .values() it returns an iterator which you don't need

```
filterPrestationsByServiceSelected(arrayOfServices) {
    console.log(arrayOfServices); // ['Repassage', 'Couture']
    this.filteredPrestationsByService = this.filteredPrestations.filter(item => item.service.name.includes(arrayOfServices));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code. I think this code will work.

```
filterPrestationsByServiceSelected(arrayOfServices) {
    console.log(arrayOfServices); // ['Repassage', 'Couture']
    this.filteredPrestationsByService = this.filteredPrestations.filter(item => arrayOfServices.includes(item.service.name));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the items of a list with another. So you would have to have a compare each element of one data structure with another. Since you are comparing arrays you should do that way:

```
filterPrestationsByServiceSelected(arrayOfServices) {
    console.log(arrayOfServices); // ['Repassage', 'Couture']
    this.filteredPrestationsByService = this.filteredPrestations.filter(item => arrayOfServices.find(e => e === item.service.name))
},
```

That way you could compare the elements one by one.